# Создание кэш-страницы для графика?

Tags: json, javascript, ajax, php

В общем, использую [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update).
Для получения данных юзаю ajax.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/convey/ajax2.php?val="+val,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
   {
```

В общем, все бы хорошо, но вот таких графиков строить нужно много и пользователей тоже много, а выгребает он немало. И база начала проседать. Подскажите, как быть.

По сути, было бы логично в первый раз грузить весь интервал, а затем дополучать след. значения. Но вот как это реализовать? json возвращает структуру данных вида

```
[
  [1147651200000,67.79],
  [1147737600000,64.98],
    [1147824000000,65.26],
   [1147910400000,63.18]
 ]
```

Как бы в конец массива данные вписать?
А может, есть другие пути?
Про highcharts, если кому интересно, [здесь](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/07/highcharthighstock.html).

Comment: Вы плохо изучили страницу, которую привели для ознакомления. Там есть ссылка на динамический график.

Comment: так там изменение сразу всех данных

Comment: > Как бы в конец массива данные вписать?

1. Прочитать и десериализовать массив
2. Добавить данные
3. Перезаписать сериализованный массив

Comment: @anunak, строка 22 (в js) http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/02/python-postgres.html

Comment: @anunak, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.